# Regular Expression to get all links with certain extensions

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Im looking for a regular expression that will grab all of the urls that have the extensions int he following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mp4
    [1] => m4v
    [2] => webm
    [3] => ogv
    [4] => wmv
    [5] => flv
)
```

This array is returned by an internal WordPress function called `wp_get_video_extensions()` and are video URls that WordPress recognizes.

A block of content would look like this with URls inside it:

> 'Yes, but I grow at a reasonable pace,' said the Dormouse: 'not in
>   that ridiculous fashion.' And he got up very sulkily and crossed over
>   to the other side of the court.
>
> All this time the Queen had never left off staring at the Hatter, and,
>   just as the Dormouse crossed the court, she said to one of the
>   officers of the court, 'Bring me the list of the singers in the last
>   concert!' on which the wretched Hatter trembled so, that he shook both
>   his shoes off.
>
> [video mp4="http://www.example.com/files/video/video1.mp4"][/video]
>
> 'Give your evidence,' the King repeated angrily, 'or I'll have you
>   executed, whether you're nervous or not.'
>
> http://www.example.com/files/video/video2.flv
>
> 'I'm a poor man, your Majesty,' the Hatter began, in a trembling
>   voice, '—and I hadn't begun my tea—not above a week or so—and what
>   with the bread-and-butter getting so thin—and the twinkling of the
>   tea—'

I am trying to get it to find both the video urls in there and return the entire URL in the array.

Here is what i have:

```
preg_match_all( '/^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:' . implode( '|', wp_get_video_extensions() ) . ')$/', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

And i am getting this:

Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '['

Ideally, i would like to get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [0] => http://www.example.com/files/video/video1.mp4
               [1] => http://www.example.com/files/video/video2.flv
           )
    [1] => Array
           (
               [0] => http://www.example.com/
               [1] => http://www.example.com/
           )
    [2] => Array
           (
               [0] => files/video/
               [1] => files/video/
           )
    [3] => Array
           (
               [0] => video1.mp4
               [1] => video2.flv
           )
)
```

But this would also be perfect as i can use `parse_url()` to break the rest out later on:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/files/video/video1.mp4
    [1] => http://www.example.com/files/video/video2.flv
)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work :(" Is really not enough information - We need to know *how* it didn't work, generally with sample input/output, and a [Short, Self Contained, Compileable Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please, [edit] the question to add information instead of using comments.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan sorry for the short reply earlier. I edited the post to include more information about exactly what i am looking for

Comment: @b__ sorry for the short reply earlier. I edited the post to include more information about exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You're first problem, is that you didn't escape all the "/". The second problem is that you're trying to match only if that is the beginning and ending of the line. This should take care of it.

```
preg_match_all('~https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:' . implode( '|', wp_get_video_extensions() ) . ')~', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

Using "~" makes it so you don't have to escape the "/".